# Help with Django localization--doesn't seem to be working. Nothing happens

Tags: python, django, localization, internationalization

Can someone help me with Localization? I put {% trans "..." %} in my template, I filled in my django.po after running "makemessages".

```
#: templates/main_content.html:136
msgid "Go to page"
msgstr "▒~C~Z▒~C▒▒~B▒▒~L~G▒~Z"

#: templates/main_content.html:138
msgid "Page"
msgstr "▒~C~Z▒~C▒▒~B▒"

#: templates/main_content.html:154
msgid "Next"
msgstr "次"
```

Then, I set LANGUAGES={} in my settings.py along with "gettext lambda":

```
gettext = lambda s: s
LANGUAGES = (
    ('de', gettext('German')),
    ('en', gettext('English')),
    ('ja', gettext('Japanese')),
)
```

Of course, I installed the LocaleMiddleware.
I also set the `request.session['django_language'] = "ja"`

How do I test that this is working? How do I see japanese on my site!?

Answer (score 0):

Set your browser (or whatever web user agent you're using to test this site) so that its `Accept-Language` request header value is `ja`.

Comment: It didn't change the text, but the response header did say "Content-Language: ja"